# Execution sequence within Process and if else : VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to do something in one clock cycle. What my approach is:

```
process begin
if rising_edge(clk) then

if (condition) then 
values of variables a and b are generated;
end if;

Here I want to use these freshly generated values of a and b.

end if;
end process;
```

The question is: May I do this, or these values of a and b will be updated at the end of the process? Or any other approach also be welcome.

Comment: Your provided code is not complete and verifiable. In addition to being a mix of VHDL and pseudo code, it misses indentations, so we can quickly read and understand your approach.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the immediate values of a and b, then a and b must be variables.
If a and b are signals, then they become registers in a pipeline, and will be available on the next clock cycle.

Comment: It is not correct that signals become registers in a process. The important point is, that signal updates are scheduled until a `wait`-statement is reached, whereas variables are updated immediately. So to read an assigned value of signal in the same process, a wait statement of at least 1-delta-cycle delay is needed: `wait for 0 ns;`. Normally, one has to wait for a process restart to read the value. If this reading is then combined with a condition, a memory element gets inferred. Based on the condition, it can be a latch or a flip-flop.

Answer (score 1):

In guessing what you want to achieve, you need variables.

Variables are updated immediately in a variable assignment, whereas sequential signal assignments as scheduled until the next `wait`-statement is reached.

Be aware, that a process' sensitivity list is a syntactic sugar for a `wait on <sensitivity list>;` statement inserted before `end process`. Thus, if a process sensitivity list is used instead of wait statements, signals become updated at the end of a process.

```
process(<sensitivity list>)
  variable a : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
begin
  a := foo;
  if (a = x"55") then
    result <= a;
  else
    result <= not a;
  end if;
end process;
```

Equivalent process with `wait on`:

```
process
  variable a : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
begin
  a := foo;
  if (a = x"55") then
    result <= a;
  else
    result <= not a;
  end if;

  wait on <sensitivity list>;
end process;
```

This also explains, why every process is evaluate at least once when a simulation starts.

Comment: Thats what I wanted to know. Thanks.